# Add method of OLEObjects class failed

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to add an Excel Document within another Excel Document using OLEObjects in Python, but I'm getting this error:

```
d:\Python\PythonReport>d:/Python27/python.exe genDP.py d:/Python/PythonReport/ATP.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genDP.py", line 219, in <module>
    add_ATP_WorkBook(OutputBook, sys.argv[1])
  File "genDP.py", line 212, in add_ATP_WorkBook
    oleObjects.Add(ClassType=None, Filename=file, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=False, Left=0, Top=0, Width=50, Height=50)
  File "<COMObject OLEObjects>", line 6, in Add
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel', u'Add method of OLEObjects class failed', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

What is strange is the fact that it works well for other files: I could easily add a text document as OLEObject, but when I try with an Excel Document I get that error.

This is the code:

```
def add_ATP_WorkBook(OutputBook, file):
    ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    ExcelApp.visible = 1
    workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.open(str(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))+"\DVPR Report.xls")
    oleObjects = workbook.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects()
    oleObjects.Add(ClassType=None, Filename=file, Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=False, Left=0, Top=0, Width=50, Height=50)
    workbook.Worksheets('Recognition Rate').Activate()
```